# Low transmit rate from distant access point

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, network-adapter, wireless-access-point

I have connected to a far away access point and the maximum link quality speed is about 65Mbps but the internet is pretty slow. The signal is 54% (good) but the link quality speed is about 11Mbps. Why is this connection operating poorly? Can a more powerful antenna fix the issue, or its because the access point is too far away?

I mean by transmit or link speed, not the real life speed.

I am connected to a regular wifi ZTE router (ADSL), by a TP-Link wifi adapter. Can I break the distance factor by buying and connecting a high gain antenna?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit of a guess, but most likely what is happening is you are picking up interference from other access points on the same or nearby channels.  If you can get 65 megabit speeds, its not because the AP is to far away - although bringing it closer can increase the signal to noise ratio and provide better throughput.

I more powerful could help as these are actually "more directional" rather then more powerful.  A directional aerial may help more.   Similarly you may be able to "do better" by changing the frequency you are transmitting on (If you don't know what else is transmitting and on what frequencies, get an android device and get the free "Wifi Analyser" program to see what is going on.

You may also have luck moving the access point.

Comment: Thank i will try to buy more powerful antenna and will get back :D